# Debugging Error in Xpath 2.0 expression

Tags: xslt, xslt-1.0

Problem in the cases in the below XSLt code, even though variables are defined, it shows undefined variable.

First choose is to test wheather the Year is for Leap year or non Leap Year.
Second choose only finds the cases for number of Days of the month.

```
<xsl:template name="CalDateNTime">
<xsl:param name="pDate"/>
<xsl:param name="pMonth"/> 
<xsl:param name="pYear"/>
<xsl:choose>
            <!--    Leap Year  -->  

    <xsl:when test="($pYear mod 4=0 and $pYear mod 100 !=0) or $pYear mod 400 =0" >

<xsl:value-of select="$pDate"/>
<xsl:value-of select="$rDate"/>
<xsl:value-of select="$pMonth"/>

    <xsl:choose>

        <xsl:when test="$pMonth=1 and $rDate=32">
        <xsl:variable name="rDate" select="1"/>
        <xsl:variable name="rMonth" select="2"/>
        </xsl:when>

        <xsl:when test="$pMonth=2 and $rDate=30">
        <xsl:variable name="rDate" select="1"/>
        <xsl:variable name="rMonth" select="3"/>
        </xsl:when>

        <xsl:when test="$pMonth=3 and $rDate=32">
        <xsl:variable name="rDate" select="1"/>
        <xsl:variable name="rMonth" select="4"/>
        </xsl:when>

    </xsl:choose>

    </xsl:when>

          <!--  Non - Leap Year  -->    
    <xsl:otherwise>
    <xsl:variable name="jan" select="31"/>
    <xsl:variable name="feb" select="28"/>
    </xsl:otherwise>
</xsl:choose>
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: You try to use an `$rDate` variable or param in the *choose* blocks, but you didn't declare any.

Comment: Identified the problem. Multiple declaration cannot be done. In the above code rDate and rMonth are declared multiple times...

Comment: That's not the only problem with your original approach, but yes.

Answer (score 1):

XSLT variables only exist within their parent.

```
<xsl:when test="$pMonth=1 and $rDate=32">
  <xsl:variable name="rDate" select="1" />
  <xsl:variable name="rMonth" select="2" />
</xsl:when>
```

These two variables are out of scope *immediately* (at the `</xsl:when>`).

You must structure your program differently. Put the `<xsl:choose>` *into* the variable.

I can only assume what your partial sample code is supposed to do. My assumption is: It should calculate the day after a given date.

Here's an alternative implementation:

```
<xsl:template name="CalDateNTime">
  <xsl:param name="pDate" />
  <xsl:param name="pMonth" /> 
  <xsl:param name="pYear" />

  <xsl:variable name="dayNum" select="'312831303130313130313031'" />
  <xsl:variable name="isLeap" select="($pYear mod 4 = 0 and $pYear mod 100 != 0) or ($pYear mod 400 = 0)" />

  <!-- determine index into the $dayNum string -->
  <xsl:variable name="idx" select="($pMonth - 1) * 2" />
  <xsl:variable name="maxDate" select="substring($dayNum, $idx + 1, 2)" />
  <xsl:variable name="isSameMonth" select="($pDate &lt; $maxDate) or ($pDate = $maxDate and $pMonth = 2 and $isLeap)" />

  <!-- calculate following day, month, year values -->
  <xsl:variable name="nDate">
    <xsl:choose>
      <xsl:when test="$isSameMonth"><xsl:value-of select="$pDate + 1" /></xsl:when>
      <xsl:otherwise>1</xsl:otherwise>
    </xsl:choose>
  </xsl:variable>
  <xsl:variable name="nMonth">
    <xsl:choose>
      <xsl:when test="$isSameMonth"><xsl:value-of select="$pMonth" /></xsl:when>
      <xsl:when test="$pMonth &lt; 12"><xsl:value-of select="$pMonth + 1" /></xsl:when>
      <xsl:otherwise>1</xsl:otherwise>
    </xsl:choose>
  </xsl:variable>
  <xsl:variable name="nYear">
    <xsl:choose>
      <xsl:when test="not($isSameMonth) and $nMonth = 1"><xsl:value-of select="$pYear + 1" /></xsl:when>
      <xsl:otherwise><xsl:value-of select="$pYear" /></xsl:otherwise>
    </xsl:choose>
  </xsl:variable>

  <!-- build output string -->
  <xsl:value-of select="concat($nYear, '-')" />
  <xsl:if test="$nMonth &lt; 10">0</xsl:if>
  <xsl:value-of select="concat($nMonth, '-')" />
  <xsl:if test="$nDate &lt; 10">0</xsl:if>
  <xsl:value-of select="$nDate" />
</xsl:template>
```

Usage

```
<xsl:call-template name="CalDateNTime">
  <xsl:with-param name="pDate" select="28" />
  <xsl:with-param name="pMonth" select="2" /> 
  <xsl:with-param name="pYear" select="2000" />
</xsl:call-template>
```

Result

```
2000-02-29
```